# hasClass not working with $(this) return

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use `hasClass` conditional with `$(this)` return but it didn't work. Here is my code;

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if($('.cn_submenu li').hasClass('current')){
       $(this).parent().show();
    }
})
```

But if I use `$('.cn_submenu')` instead of `$(this)` it can works.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect what you're *really* trying to do is to show the parent of any `li` with class `active` within a `.cn_submenu`. Your current code looks to see if the **first** `li` of the **first** `.cn_submenu` has the class `active` (ignoring all other `.cn_submenu` and `li` elements), and then uses `this` incorrectly if so.

To show the parent of any `li` with class `active` that's inside a `.cn_submenu`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".cn_submenu li.active").parent().show();
});
```

How that works:

- `$(".cn_submenu li.active")` selects any `li` elements with the class `active` that are descendants of a `.cn_submenu`.
- `.parent()` finds the (unique) set of immediate parents of those elements.
- `.show()` shows them (if any).

Comment: Yeah, you got me! Thanks T.J!

Answer (score 1):

`this` refers to `document` in your question, so you're trying to `show()` the parent of `document`.  Use `$('.cn_submenu')` instead.